# How to create two layers with shared weights, where one is the transpose of the other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am using the Keras API in Tensorflow 2.0.

As an example, say I want to have two dense layers in my model, called `layer1` and `layer2`. But I want to tie their weights, such that the weight matrix in `layer1` always equals the transpose of the weight matrix from `layer2`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a custom Keras layer for that, where you can pass reference `Dense` layer.

Custom Dense Layer:

```
class CustomDense(Layer):
    def __init__(self, reference_layer):
      super(CustomDense, self).__init__()
      self.ref_layer = reference_layer

    def call(self, inputs):
        weights = self.ref_layer.get_weights()[0]
        bias = self.ref_layer.get_weights()[1]
        weights = tf.transpose(weights)
        x = tf.linalg.matmul(inputs, weights) + bias
        return x
```

Now you add this layer to your model using [Functional-API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional).

```
inp = Input(shape=(5))
dense = Dense(5)
transposed_dense = CustomDense(dense)

#model
x = dense(inp)
x = transposed_dense(x)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
model.summary()
'''
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 5)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 30        
_________________________________________________________________
custom_dense_1 (CustomDense) (None, 5)                 30        
=================================================================
Total params: 30
Trainable params: 30
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
'''
```

As you can see `dense` and `custom_dense` shares 30 parameters. Here `custom_dense` is just doing dense operation using transposed weights of `dense` layer and it has no parameter of it's own.

**EDIT 1: Answering question in comment (How sub-classed layer gets #params?):**

Layer class tracks all objects being passed to it's `__init__` method.

```
transposed_dense._layers
# [<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7fc3e0874f28>]
```

Above parameter will give dependent layers that are being tracked. 
All child attribute weights can be viewed as:

```
transposed_dense._gather_children_attribute("weights")
#[<tf.Variable 'dense_9/kernel:0' shape=(10, 5) dtype=float32>,
# <tf.Variable 'dense_9/bias:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32>]
```

Hence when we call `model.summary()` It internally calls `count_params()` for each `Layer`, which counts all [trainable_variable](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e5bf8de410005de06a7ff5393fafdf832ef1d4ad/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/data_structures.py#L196) including self and children attributes.

Comment: Looks good, although I wonder where does Keras get the 30 `Param #` from for `custom_dense_1`, since the layer itself is not holding references to any weight...